# How to redirect from one web directory to another with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, redirect

Apache2
Plesk 9.x

I have a website www.example.com
and my blog is on www.example.com/blog

I have no content on www.example.com as of now
So I want all requests for example.com to be redirected to www.example.com/blog

How should I do that ? Is this something I can do in Apache?

I am using the GoDaddy DNS server.
Not sure if it matters- but I have multiple domains hosted n the same server. And I am using Plesk to manage my virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file in your DocumentRoot and add these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ /blog [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

To answer your question about DNS settings, no, those don't matter. DNS is only concerned with the "domain" portion of the URL, not what follows it in the url path.

Comment: You just created an infinite redirect loop, he wants to redirect to the same domain.

Comment: You're right. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is by creating an index.php file in your `DocumentRoot` with the following content:

```
<?php
header("Location: www.example.com/blog/"); 
?>
```

Comment: Why bring php into the equation when you can do it with apache alone?